# Is there a way to make Path immutable?

Tags: android

A Path object comes with many methods that changes it (`moveTo()`, `lineTo()`, `cubicTo()`, `arcTo()`, `reset()`, etc.).

Is there a way to freeze the object once you have it the way you want it, before you pass it onward?

Something along the line of `CGPath` in objective-c?

Comment: If you want to know how to make an Object immmutable https://www.journaldev.com/129/how-to-create-immutable-class-in-java

Comment: I suppose you could subclass it, override all the mutators, and have them unconditionally throw exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Immutable means that once the constructor for an object has completed execution that instance can't be altered.

Still, you can subclass `Path` and add pseudo-immutability yourself if that's really needed but there is no built-in mechanism out of the box.

Comment: I guess it made enough sense for apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath "An immutable graphics path" ; Also, in my scenario I want to protect my render thread from reading paths that are still changing and Immutable objects are usually the go-to method. Of course you can do without it, but you could also do without ImmutableList, etc. and still they exist.

Comment: You talk android, not ios, so it's irrelevant what Apple is doing. Path on android is mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but an alternative solution to the problem you are describing is to copy of the original `Path` using the constructor:

```
Path copy = new Path(originalPath);
```

Then, you can pass the copy the other thread without worrying if they change it while you are reading the original `Path`.